# Favorite plug-ins for building creature vocals

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, creature-vocalizations

Besides the obvious like pitch shift, I have a few favorites such as Prosoniq's Morph and PiWarp, iZotope Spectron, and GRM tools as well as some of the Pluggo suite.  What are your favorite plug-ins for use in building creature vocals?

(Edited because I feel like I gave the wrong impression with the initial question -- I'm not saying "please tell me which plug-in will magically create great creature sounds," but rather "I'm curious as to which plug-ins you've had good results with, and for which specific aspects of the vocals you were creating."  Obviously, creature creation is a lot more complicated (and fun) than passing a recording through some wondrous RydstromVox Plus plug-in. :) Sorry if it sounded like that's what I was asking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plug-ins are an valuable part of the sound designer's arsenal, but I think it's critical to stress the importance of choosing the right sounds early on so that plug-in manipulation is kept to a minimum, or at least focused on a particular type of plug-in such as pitch shift or phasing. The place you don't want to find yourself is using the *wrong sound* which requires extensive manipulation to start sounding *right*.

That said, I find the following plug-ins valuable most of the time, in varying doses:

- Pitch n Time
- Waves LoAir
- Waves MondoMod
- Digi Reverse
- Waves L1
- Digi EQ3

With the right sounds and some of those plug-ins, you should be more than covered.

**REMEMBER, IT'S NOT THE TOOLS BUT THE TALENT WHO IS USING THE TOOLS!**

Comment: I concur - the right ingredients are necessary to make a tasty sound, and overprocessing the wrong source is a poor practice.

Comment: @Jay Sometimes a touch of Doubler creates interesting tonalities with the mono phasing.  Gotta be careful with that one though - a little bit can go a long way (in the wrong sense)

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with you Jay

For me it would be mostly altering appropriate source material with Audiosuite plugins, like pitch, time expansion, reversing... I like AudioSculpt app for doing subtle pitch bends too... I know a few people who have messed with that Antares Throat plugin & gotten interesting results - it models the throat & vocal tract:
http://www.antarestech.com/products/avox.shtml

Comment: @tim AudioSculpt looks interesting -- I hadn't seen that one before.  I've heard of Antares Throat but have never used it, let alone on non-human material.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

How about [SpectrumWorx](https://www.littleendian.com/consumers/spectrumworx/) sound mangler?